# Jest cannot find node modules

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing

On my NestJs app, Jest E2E test file is throwing the following error :

> Cannot find module '@azure/msal-node' from 'src/utilities/testUtils.ts'

Which really suprising since other azure modules are used all around the app and don't throw any error.

app.e2e-spec.ts

```
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import request from 'supertest';
import { AppModule } from './../src/app.module';
import getTokenFromCredentials from 'src/utilities/testUtils';

describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let token: string;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    token = await getTokenFromCredentials();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it('GET /', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/').expect(200);
  });

  it('GET /absences', async () => {
    const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/absences')
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

    expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
  });
});
```

src/utilities/testUtils.ts

```
import { ConfidentialClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-node';

async function getTokenFromCredentials(): Promise<string> {
  const config = {
    auth: {
      clientId: process.env.MSAL_CLIENT_ID,
      authority: process.env.MSAL_AUTHORITY,
      clientSecret: process.env.MSAL_CLIENT_CREDENTIAL,
    },
  };

  const app = new ConfidentialClientApplication(config);
  const res = await app.acquireTokenByUsernamePassword({
    username: process.env.MSAL_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.MSAL_PASSWORD,
    scopes: [process.env.MSAL_SCOPES],
  });

  return res.accessToken;
}

export default getTokenFromCredentials;
```

jest-e2e.json

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "."]
}
```

Everything seems to be installed at the right place.

I tried to remove *node_modules* and *package-lock.json* and rerun `npm i`, **didn't work**.

I tried various configuration for the `jest-e2e.json`, particularly on the *moduleNameMapper* param to map directly on the dist folder inside the *node_modules*, **didn't work**.

It's really suprising since using another azure module inside `testUtils.ts` file is working correctly and using *@azure/msal-node* directly inside a service or something is working too.